# Finding distributions on $\mathbb{R^2}$ constrained by 2 equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

The question asks us to classify all distributions in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $u$, such that $$(xy)u(x,y) = (x^2-y^2)u(x,y)= 0.$$

I am genuinely stuck, any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Hard to understand ! What do you mean by $xy(u) = (x^2-y^2)(u)= 0$ ? Is it $xy(u)=x*y*u$ ? Is U a distribution in the sense of theory of distributions ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I apologize, it is true that U is a distribution in the familiar sense of theory of distributions, and here I've surmised that it  is not convolution but rather multiplication that we are dealing with.

Comment: The parentheses make it look like application, but I assume that you mean that $u(x,y)$ (where the arguments are formal) is multiplied by $x$ and $y$ in the left hand side, and by $x^2-y^2$ in the right hand side. Correct?

Comment: @md2perpe yes that's correct

Comment: This query is in danger of being closed.  If it is closed, the query will
not be able to receive more answers at mathSE.
I think mathSE reviewers want you to explicitly edit your query to clarify what your math question is and to share what work you have done and what your thoughts are.

Answer (score 3):

Solving $xy \, u(x,y)=0$:

We know that $x\,v(x)=0$ has solutions $v(x)=C\,\delta(x),$ where $C$ is a constant. Generalizing this we get that $y\,u(x,y) = A(y)\,\delta(x)$ for some distribution $A(y).$ Then $u(x,y) = B(y)\,\delta(x) + C(x)\,\delta(y),$ where $A(y)=y\,B(y)$ and $C(x)$ is some distribution. Thus,
$$
u(x,y) = \delta(x) \otimes B(y) + C(x) \otimes \delta(y),
$$
where $B(y)$ and $C(x)$ are some distributions.

We want to find solutions that also satisfy $(x^2-y^2)\,u(x,y)=0,$ i.e.
$$
0 
= (x^2-y^2)(\delta(x) \otimes B(y) + C(x) \otimes \delta(y))
= \delta(x) \otimes (-y^2)\,B(y) + x^2\,C(x) \otimes \delta(y)
$$
since $x^2\,\delta(x)=0=y^2\,\delta(y).$

Thus we shall have $\delta(x) \otimes y^2\,B(y) = x^2\,C(x) \otimes \delta(y)$ meaning that
$$
\begin{cases}
\delta(x) = \lambda \, x^2\,C(x) \\
y^2\,B(y) = \lambda^{-1} \delta(y) \\
\end{cases}
$$
for some constant $\lambda.$

The solutions to these two equations are,
$$\begin{align}
B(y) &= \frac12 \lambda^{-1}\, \delta''(y) + E\,\delta'(y) + F\,\delta(y) \\
C(x) &= \frac12 \lambda \,\delta''(x) + G\,\delta'(x) + H\,\delta(x) \\
\end{align}$$
where $E,F,G,H$ are constants.

Thus,
$$
u(x,y) 
= \delta(x) \otimes (\frac12 \lambda^{-1}\, \delta''(y) + E\,\delta'(y) + F\,\delta(y)) 
+ (\frac12 \lambda \,\delta''(x) + G\,\delta'(x) + H\,\delta(x)) \otimes \delta(y)
.
$$

Comment: Why did the $\delta(x)$ change to $\delta(y)$ in the third line from the top?

Comment: [+1] Very good solution !

Comment: @BrazyOski. I don't understand where you think $\delta(x)$ changes to $\delta(y)$.

Comment: figured it out @md2perpe